# Delete all but 3 images for any product

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table where Products are mapping with Pictures. There are products which have 1 to n mappings with pictures. To view the mappings nicely I've build an SQL so I can view them grouped by ProductId.

```
    SELECT  [Id]
      ,[ProductId]
      ,[PictureId]
      ,[DisplayOrder]
FROM [LandOgFritid23].[dbo].[Product_Picture_Mapping]
Where ProductId in (select ProductId
                    FROM [LandOgFritid23].[dbo].Product p,
                    [LandOgFritid23].[dbo].[Product_Picture_Mapping] pm
                    where p.Id = pm.ProductId
                    group by ProductId
                    having COUNT(pm.PictureId) > 3
                    )
order by ProductId
```

The Result:

```
Id  ProductId   PictureId   DisplayOrder
2085    103    2388         2
2185    103    2488         1
7132    103    7468         1
7133    103    7469         1
2158    107    2461         0
320     107    415          1
3485    107    3816         1
3486    107    3817         1
3529    107    3860         1
```

Now, the request is to only let 3 pictures MAX for each product. I find it very hard to CREATE a DELETE statement for deleting any row which is the 4th, 5th, nth one mapping for a product.

Do you have any ideea if this is possible?

So the results after deleting, with this data will be:

```
Id  ProductId   PictureId   DisplayOrder
2085    103    2388         2
2185    103    2488         1
7132    103    7468         1
2158    107    2461         0
320     107    415          1
3485    107    3816         1
```

Thanks

Comment: Database normalization proponents might scream, but if you really want to limit it to 3 pictures, you could put 3 fields in the Product table.

Comment: @KendallFrey yes, sure, but here was a problem of code and this is PRODUCTION DB which might be clean:) and I was trying to do this from sql...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a CTE:

Note: Assuming you want to keep the latest 3 pictures

```
WITH Data AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY PictureId DESC) 
            AS Position
     FROM [LandOgFritid23].[dbo].[Product_Picture_Mapping]
 )
 DELETE 
    FROM Data
 WHERE Position > 3
```

Comment: This is awesome... I wasn't aware of such great features of Sql Server!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() partitioning by PictureId and ordering by the appropriate fields to determine the first three records.

Note that I'm assuming here you're using the DisplayOrder field in descending order to determine ordering:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  [Id]
          ,[ProductId]
          ,[PictureId]
          ,[DisplayOrder]
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY DisplayOrder DESC) as PicNum
    FROM [LandOgFritid23].[dbo].[Product_Picture_Mapping]
    Where ProductId in (select ProductId
                        FROM [LandOgFritid23].[dbo].Product p,
                        [LandOgFritid23].[dbo].[Product_Picture_Mapping] pm
                        where p.Id = pm.ProductId
                        group by ProductId
                        having COUNT(pm.PictureId) > 3
                        )
) x
WHERE x.PicNum <= 3
ORDER BY ProductId, PicNum
```

I'm guessing that you're doing a separate query to get all products that have three or less pictures?  You could do the entire thing in one query, simply by removing the the WHERE clause and subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  [Id]
          ,[ProductId]
          ,[PictureId]
          ,[DisplayOrder]
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY DisplayOrder DESC) as PicNum
    FROM [LandOgFritid23].[dbo].[Product_Picture_Mapping]
) x
WHERE x.PicNum <= 3
ORDER BY ProductId, PicNum
```